# Find the file offset for a character index, ignoring newline

Tags: text, indexing, data-structures, bioinformatics

I have a text file of 3GB size (a FASTA file with DNA sequences). It contains about 50 million lines of differing
length, though the most lines are 70 characters wide. I want to extract a string from this file, given two character indices. The difficult
part is, that newlines shall not be counted as character.

For good speed, I want to use `seek()` to reach the beginning of the string and start reading, but I need the offset in bytes for that.

My current approach is to write a new file, with all the newlines removed, but that takes another 3GB on disk. I want to find a solution which requires less disk space.

Using a dictionary mapping each character count to a file offset is not practicable either, because there would be one key for every byte, therefore using at least 16bytes*3 billion characters = 48GB.

I think I need a data structure which allows to retrieve the number of newline characters that come before a character of certain index, then I can add their number and the character index to obtain the file offset in bytes.

Comment: What do you mean "given two character indices". do you mean you want to get sub sequences from `begin..end` ?

Comment: Can't you just store the length of each line, then use that info to calculate the byte offset?

Comment: @dkatzel Exactly that.

Comment: @heathobrien Yes that is a way. My question is focussed on how to do this most efficiently. For example for each character index I could iterate through all the stored character indices until the first is greater than the one I am looking for. My question aims at maybe some data structure which is a good way to store this information and is maybe more efficient than a simple dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SamTools `fai` index was designed just for this purpose. Which makes a very small compact index file with enough information to quickly seek to any point in the fasta file for any record inside as long as the file is properly formatted

You can create a SamTools index using `samtools faidx` command.

You can then use other programs in the SamTools package to pull out subsequences or alignments very quickly using the index.

see http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools.html for usage.

Comment: I didn't know samtools supports extraction of subsequences! According to https://www.biostars.org/p/10469/, a command like `samtools faidx reference.fasta lyrata:1-108` is possible.